# changing 2nd spinner values on changing 1st spinner value

Tags: java, android, spinner

I am learning android spinners.

I have two spinners in my app.

I want to change Item value of second spinner on changing(Or selecting) item value of first spinner.

How I can do this ?

Can any one provide any sample code or link, which will help me ?

And Sorry if, I am repeating the question again.

Comment: Put a OnItemSelectedListener() on the first spinner, adding your own listener which initializes the second spinner with the correct values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes here is the link, the holy android docs http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html

You need to implement an OnItemSelectedListener and set it on the first spinner as shown in the docs.

Then you call setSelection on the other Spinner in the onItemSelected callback.